# How can a font awesome icon be added into a reset button?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to replace the `RESET` text within a form `reset button` to just a `Font Awesome Icon (specifically: fa fa-refresh)`. How can I do this?

**Code:**

```html
<div class="form-actions col-sm-12">
  <?php if ($showResetButton) { ?>
  <input type="reset" id="reset" class="button button-dark button-3d" value="Reset">
  <?php } ?>
  <input type="submit" class="button button-3d" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Comment: have you included the necessary ccs file to your page?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unicode. You will find [unicode for refresh icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/refresh) here. But you need to use font family css attribute.

```css
#reset{
font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

<div class="form-actions col-sm-12">
    <?php if ($showResetButton) { ?> <input type="reset" id="reset" class="button button-dark button-3d" value="Reset &#xf021;"> <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" class="button button-3d" value="Search"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using  you could use

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
Reset</button>
```

and then include the needed  tag inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

Here your code:

```
    <div class="form-actions col-sm-12">
        <?php if ($showResetButton) { ?> 
         <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-warning">
        Search <i class='fa fa-refresh'></i>
        </button><?php } ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        Search <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
        </button>

    </div>`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="form-actions col-sm-12">
        <?php if ($showResetButton) { ?> 
         <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-warning">
        Reset <i class='fa fa-refresh'></i>
        </button><?php } ?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        Search <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
        </button>
         
    </div>
```